# Minimum size implementation for bool array

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I need a minimum size implementation of an array of bools. The size of the array is known at compile time.

I checked `std::bitset` and `boost::array`, but they both incur an overhead that is significant for small arrays. For example, if the array size is **8**, the container should only use **1 byte** of memory (assuming common CPU architecture).

Does this exist or do I need to roll my own?

Comment: `std:bitset` should only use one bit per element (as `std::vector<bool>` does in some implementations). How did you check that it uses more?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi if you do `sizeof(std::vector<bool>)` it returns 40

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi:
Using sizeof operator.
This is part of the implementation, it uses dynamic allocation:
 _WordT *_M_wp;
 size_t _M_bpos;
May be different for other std implementations

Comment: @Tony, that's its "static" size (an instance of `std::vector<bool>` weights 40 bytes even when empty). It does not take into account the heap memory allocated for the elements themselves.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi right, but then that means adding elements will only make it larger, no?

Comment: @Tony, indeed, but `sizeof()` will still return `40` then.

Comment: You could make your own version of `bitset` by copy-paste and changing `typedef unsigned long _WordT;` to char

Comment: @Gabriel, if I understand your comment correctly, you want the container to only occupy the storage required for its elements. That's generally not the case (a pointer to the elements and an element count are usually implemented, and there can be more members). You might be looking for a custom array of bits instead of a full-fledged container.

Comment: @GabrielSchreiber hey gabriel. Answers should not be part of the question. Would you be so kind and extract your implementation into a new answer? You don't have any recent activity, so I'll do it for you in the meantime. If you ever get to do it yourself, I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example. Please note that it only does what it needs to, so you won't be able to iterate it like a `std::bitset`.

```
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

template<int S> struct boolset {
    static int const SIZE = ((S / CHAR_BIT) + (0 != (S % CHAR_BIT)));
    unsigned char m_bits[SIZE];
public:
    boolset() : m_bits() { for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) m_bits[i] = 0; }

    bool get(int i) const {
        assert(i < S);
        return (m_bits[i / CHAR_BIT] & (1 << (i % CHAR_BIT)));
    }

    void set(int i, bool v) {
        assert(i < S);
        if(v) { m_bits[i / CHAR_BIT] |= (1 << (i % CHAR_BIT)); }
        else { m_bits[i / CHAR_BIT] &= ~(1 << (i % CHAR_BIT)); }
    }

    void print(std::ostream & s) const {
        for(int i = 0; i < S; ++i) {
            s << get(i);
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    std::cout << sizeof(boolset<1>) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(boolset<8>) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(boolset<9>) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(boolset<16>) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(boolset<17>) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(boolset<32>) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(boolset<33>) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(boolset<64>) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(boolset<129>) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    boolset<31> bs;
    bs.set(0, true);
    bs.set(28, true);
    bs.set(2, true);
    std::cout << bs.get(28) << std::endl;
    bs.print(std::cout); std::cout << std::endl;
    bs.set(2, false);
    bs.print(std::cout); std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Output on [ideone](http://ideone.com/WH1W22).

Comment: Learned something new: static members of course depend on template params. Didn't quite realize this before.

Answer (score 3):

You can make it by your own, but not from scratch. `bitset` implementation should have a couple of lines looking like `typedef unsigned long _WordT;` (SGI) or `typedef _Uint32t _Ty;` (MSVS). You could carefully replace the type and namespace and make your own container this way. I changed the type to char and `sizeof` returns 1 (vs2010 proof-of-concept on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/BYVgMYyH))

Answer (score 2):

```
template <int N>
class BitSet {
    enum { BPC = 8 }; // Bits per char, #ifdef as needed
    char m_bits[ (N + (BPC-1)) / BPC ];
public:
void SetBit( int i ) { m_bits[ i / BPC ] |= 1 << (i % BPC); }
void ClearBit( int i ) { m_bits[ i / BPC ] &= ~(1 << (i % BPC)); }
int GetBit( int i ) { return (m_bits[ i / BPC ] >> (i % BPC)) & 1; }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you did something like this:

```
#include<vector>
#include <iostream>
template<int N>
struct array
{
   char bits : N;

   int getNthbit(int bitnr)
   {
      // important to make sure bitnr is not larger than the size of the type of `bits` in number of `CHAR_BITS` 
      return bits & (1 << bitnr);
   }
};

//Specialize for N > 8

int main()
{
   std::cout << sizeof(array<8>);
}
```

If you look at the [Live Example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1rtG1r$10), you'll see when `N == 8` it returns `1` for `sizeof(array<8>)`.

When you put in 32 it returns 4.

The only thing you'd need to do is specialize the template for `N > 8` so that the type changes to fit the number of bits.

I'm no template genius, maybe someone cares to write an example?

Comment: Yes, an array char[number_of_bits % 8] is basically what I have in mind as data structure. But I need accessors doing the bit shifting and was wondering if this exists already.

Comment: @GabrielSchreiber I have never seen it, but I can't imagine writing the accessors for bit N is hard.

Comment: @TonyTheLion I am afraid this implementation will not work for N > 8, and it will certainly not work for N > 64.

Comment: @anatolyg out of curiousity, what would be the problem? I'd like to learn from this.

Comment: The expression `1 << bitnr` is implementation-defined for large values of `bitnr` (large means that it overflows the `int` type). However, some tinkering with your Live Example shows that at least the `sizeof` output behaves well.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>**Disclaimer**: I extracted this answer from the OPs question. [Answers should not be contained in the question itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309555/316262).</sub>

---

#### Answer provided by [Gabriel Schreiber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/427532/gabriel-schreiber):

Here is my final implementation based on the [post of Tom Knapen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15338098/4298200).
I added a default value for the constructor and added throwing in case of out-of-bounds index.
Many thanks to Tom and everyone else.

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <climits>

/// Minimum size container for bool-arrays
/**
 * TODO: may want to add to_uint32_t accessor and the like
 * for sufficently small arrays
 */
template<int SIZE>
class bitarray
{
public:
    bitarray(bool initial_value = false);

    bool get(int index) const;
    void set(int index, bool value);

private:
    static const int ARRAY_SIZE = (SIZE + CHAR_BIT - 1) / 8;
    unsigned char mBits[ARRAY_SIZE];
};

// ----------------------------------------------------
//      Definitions
// ----------------------------------------------------

template<int SIZE>
inline bitarray<SIZE>::bitarray(bool initial_value)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)
        mBits[i] = initial_value ? -1 : 0;
}

template<int SIZE>
inline bool bitarray<SIZE>::get(int index) const
{
    if (index >= SIZE)
        throw std::out_of_range("index out of range");
    return (mBits[index / CHAR_BIT] & (1 << (index % CHAR_BIT)));
}

template<int SIZE>
inline void bitarray<SIZE>::set(int index, bool value)
{
    if (index >= SIZE)
        throw std::out_of_range("index out of range");
    if (value)
        mBits[index / CHAR_BIT] |= (1 << (index % CHAR_BIT));
    else
        mBits[index / CHAR_BIT] &= ~(1 << (index % CHAR_BIT));
}
```

Comment: Gabriel, if you ever want to post this as your own answer, @ me in the comments and I'll remove my answer